# compare occurrence of a set of words

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, grep

I have a text file with random words in it. i want to find out which words have maximum occurrence as a pair('hi,hello' OR 'Good,Bye').

Simple.txt

```
hi there. hello this a dummy file. hello world. you did good job. bye for now.
```

I have written this command to get the count for each word(hi,hello,good,bye).

```
cat simple.txt| tr -cs '[:alnum:]' '[\n*]' | sort | uniq -c|grep -E -i  "\<hi\>|\<hello\>|\<good\>|\<bye\>"
```

this gives me the the occurrence of each word with a count(number of times it occurs) in the file but now how to refine this and get a direct output as "Hi/hello is the pair with maximum occurrence"

Comment: Is the "maximum occurrence as a pair (x,y)": a) the sum of the occurrences of x and y, or b) the number of times x and y appear side by side?

Comment: the sum of the occurrences of x and y. the dont need to appear side by side.. they are just words in text file, can appear anywhere.in this case one pair will be (hi,hello) and other will be (good,bye)

Answer (score 3):

To make it more interesting, let's consider this test file:

```
$ cat >file.txt
You say hello.  I say good bye.  good bye. good bye.
```

To get a count of all pairs of words:

```
$ awk -v RS='[[:space:][:punct:]]+' 'NR>1{a[last","$0]++} {last=$0} END{for (pair in a) print a[pair], pair}' file.txt
3 good,bye
1 say,good
2 bye,good
1 I,say
1 You,say
1 hello,I
1 say,hello
```

To get the single pair with the highest count, we need to sort:

```
$ awk -v RS='[[:space:][:punct:]]+' 'NR>1{a[last","$0]++} {last=$0} END{for (pair in a) print a[pair], pair}' file.txt | sort -nr | head -1
3 good,bye
```

#### How it works

- `-v RS='[[:space:][:punct:]]+'`

  This tells awk to use any combination of white space or punctuation as a record separator.  This means that each word becomes a record.
- `NR>1{a[last","$0]++}`

  For every word after the first, increment the count in associative array `a` for the combination of the previous and current work.
- `last=$0`

  Save the current word in the variable `last`.
- `END{for (pair in a) print a[pair], pair}`

  After we have finished reading the input, print out the results for each pair.
- `sort -nr`

  Sort the output numerically in reverse (highest number first) order.
- `head -1`

  Select the first line (giving us the pair with the highest count).

#### Multiline version

For those who prefer their code spread out over multiple lines:

```
awk -v RS='[[:space:][:punct:]]+' '
    NR>1 {
        a[last","$0]++
    }

    {
        last=$0
    }

    END {
        for (pair in a)
            print a[pair], pair
    }' file.txt | sort -nr | head -1
```

Answer (score 1):

some terse perl:

```
perl -MList::Util=max,sum0 -slne '
    for $word (m/(\w+)/g) {$count{$word}++}
 } END {
    $pair{$_} = sum0 @count{+split} for ($a, $b);
    $max = max values %pair;
    print "$max => ", {reverse %pair}->{$max};
' -- -a="hi hello" -b="good bye" simple.txt
```

```
3 => hi hello
```

Comment: appreciate the effort but i am trying to do it only by bash commands, looking to avoid perl

Comment: Hate to break it to you but none of these are "bash" commands: cat, tr, sort, uniq, grep, awk